# Setting permissions to default on Windows 10 cmd line, icacls or similar?

Tags: windows

I'm trying to reset permissions for directories. I found icacls /reset, but that sets files to inherit from the "Parent Object" (directories work fine). Is there another tool, or another way to use icacls to set my files to inherit permissions from C:\Users\username, or D:\, or wherever the default is for new files in a location?

Comment: No, Windows doesn't keep track of what the original permissions are for any particular object.  You'll have to look at another machine to find what the permissions are supposed to be, and then explicitly set them.

Comment: Windows has inheritance, and icacls does this for directories. The implementation for files isn't working properly.

Comment: `icacls /reset` on a file changes the ACL to whatever is inherited from the directory the file is in.  (That's what "Parent Object" means, the directory is the parent of the files it contains.)  What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: All of my other files have permissions inherited from D:\, while these icacls /reset files have the "Parent Object" permissions. It seems like bad form to leave it a scattered mess like this.

Comment: Curious.  Using `icacls` (with no options, just a filename) please compare a file that is "inherited from D:\" to a file that is "Parent Object".  Preferably, copy and paste the output into your question.

Comment: For a directory and a single file within, it's just this: icacls testdir /reset /t /c /l /q, then Successfully processed 2 files; Failed processing 0 files.

Comment: No, with no options - just `icacls testdir\file`, it will show you what the permissions are.

Comment: If the parent directory's DACL is protected, it breaks the chain of inheritance. For example if "D:\Temp" is protected, then "D:\Temp\testdir" does not inherit from "D:\", and `icacls "D:\Temp\testdir" /reset` won't and shouldn't change this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides Property -> Security of a folder/file, another way to do this is using `Get-Acl and Set-Acl` using PowerShell. Follow this guide: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johan/2008/10/01/powershell-editing-permissions-on-a-file-or-folder/ 
An easy way to see the Read/Write permissions on your files, I recommend this tool: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/accessenum

Answer (score 2):

on a stand-alone instance of Windows [10] there are usually four groups:

```
        NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
        NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
        BUILTIN\Administrators
        BUILTIN\Users
```

each file and each folder has access settings for each group:

```
        NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
        NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
        BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
        BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
```

in addition to that, each folder has inheritance settings for each group

```
        NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
        NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)
        BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
        BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
```

the command `icacls /reset` will set the default ACL of a file or folder to whatever is inherited from the folder it is in

in order to reset a folder with all included files and subfolders to the default it will take three steps:

1. open elevated cmd (not PowerShell)
2. take ownership of all files and folders, if necessary (to be able to change ACLs in the first place)
3. set the correct ACLs of the topmost folder, including inheritance
4. reset the ACLs for everything below this topmost folder

Step by step:

1. take ownership with:

```
    takeown.exe /d y /r /a /f <topmost_folder>
```

2. set the Windows default ACLs of the topmost folder with:

```
    icacls <topmost_folder> /remove:d SYSTEM                /grant SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(IO)F
    icacls <topmost_folder> /remove:d "Authenticated Users" /grant "Authenticated Users":(OI)(CI)(IO)M
    icacls <topmost_folder> /remove:d Administrators        /grant Administrators:(OI)(CI)(IO)F
    icacls <topmost_folder> /remove:d Users                 /grant Users:(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
```

note: /remove:d deletes all "deny" ACLs (which would override "grant" ACLs)

note: to *replace* the ACLs, instead of adding to them, use 'grant:r' instead of 'grant'

note: if you don't care for individual permissions and just want everyone to be able to access the files, use: `icacls <topmost_folder> /remove:d Everyone /grant:r Everyone:F`

3. reset ACLs for everything below the topmost folder to the ACLs of the topmost folder with:

```
    icacls <topmost_folder> /reset /t /l /c /q
```

Hope that helps.